# How data is stored physically in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I navigate to Data directory of elastic search  :

/nodes/0/indices/gb

Here what tree command shows :

```
├── 0
│   ├── index
│   │   ├── segments_6
│   │   └── write.lock
│   ├── _state
│   │   └── state-6.st
│   └── translog
│       ├── translog-1.ckp
│       ├── translog-2.ckp
│       ├── translog-3.ckp
│       ├── translog-4.ckp
│       ├── translog-5.ckp
│       ├── translog-5.tlog
│       ├── translog-6.ckp
│       ├── translog-6.tlog
│       ├── translog-7.tlog
│       └── translog.ckp
├── 1
│   ├── index
│   │   ├── _0_1.liv
│   │   ├── _0.cfe
│   │   ├── _0.cfs
│   │   ├── _0.si
│   │   ├── _1.cfe
│   │   ├── _1.cfs
│   │   ├── _1.si
│   │   ├── segments_9
│   │   └── write.lock
│   ├── _state
│   │   └── state-6.st
│   └── translog
│       ├── translog-2.ckp
│       ├── translog-3.ckp
│       ├── translog-4.ckp
│       ├── translog-5.ckp
│       ├── translog-9.tlog
│       └── translog.ckp
├── 2
│   ├── index
│   │   ├── _0.cfe
│   │   ├── _0.cfs
│   │   ├── _0.si
│   │   ├── segments_7
│   │   └── write.lock
│   ├── _state
│   │   └── state-6.st
│   └── translog
│       ├── translog-2.ckp
│       ├── translog-3.ckp
│       ├── translog-4.ckp
│       ├── translog-5.ckp
│       ├── translog-6.ckp
│       ├── translog-6.tlog
│       ├── translog-7.ckp
│       ├── translog-7.tlog
│       ├── translog-8.tlog
│       └── translog.ckp
├── 3
│   ├── index
│   │   ├── _0.cfe
│   │   ├── _0.cfs
│   │   ├── _0.si
│   │   ├── segments_7
│   │   └── write.lock
│   ├── _state
│   │   └── state-6.st
│   └── translog
│       ├── translog-2.ckp
│       ├── translog-3.ckp
│       ├── translog-4.ckp
│       ├── translog-5.ckp
│       ├── translog-6.ckp
│       ├── translog-6.tlog
│       ├── translog-7.ckp
│       ├── translog-7.tlog
│       ├── translog-8.tlog
│       └── translog.ckp
├── 4
│   ├── index
│   │   ├── _0.cfe
│   │   ├── _0.cfs
│   │   ├── _0.si
│   │   ├── segments_7
│   │   └── write.lock
│   ├── _state
│   │   └── state-6.st
│   └── translog
│       ├── translog-2.ckp
│       ├── translog-3.ckp
│       ├── translog-4.ckp
│       ├── translog-5.ckp
│       ├── translog-6.ckp
│       ├── translog-6.tlog
│       ├── translog-7.ckp
│       ├── translog-7.tlog
│       ├── translog-8.tlog
│       └── translog.ckp
└── _state
    └── state-8.st
```

Which of the file contains actual data  ? How can I see That ?

Answer (score 4):

All those files contain data and each contains a specific type of data (inverted index, field data, document values, etc). The files in the `index` sub-folder are [files created by Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/package-summary.html#package_description) in order to store all the needed data:

- `cfe` and `cfs` files are [compound files](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50CompoundFormat.html)
- `liv` files are [live document files](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50LiveDocsFormat.html)
- `si` files are [segment info files](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.html)
- ...

There are many more file types available (term frequency, term proximity, etc) as can be seen in the first link I gave above. All those files are binary files that you cannot simply view with a text editor. You can use the [Luke tool](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) from the Lucene Toolbox in order to view the content of those files.

Comment: Thanks for Answer Val. I tried to use luke tool . But it not able to open any index in elastic search data directory . Its is giving read past EOF . I tried to delete and recreated index , still its giving same issue . Any idea how to solve that problem ?