# how to print the inverted index of a type inside elasicsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, inverted-index

Elasticsearch maintain an [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/inverted-index.html) for every type .
For the sake of learning , how can I **display/print** the inverted index of specific type using elastic api/endpoints?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817542/how-data-is-stored-physically-in-elastic-search/37819282#37819282

Comment: luke tool doesnt let me open any index file.. like the user from the original post commented

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: Maybe try with a more recent release of Luke: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke

Comment: es 5.5,latest one