# On which file does elasticsearch store its data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two questions.
1.I have indexed some documents to my elasticsearch cluster (running on local machine) and some files like (_0.cfe,_0.cfs,_0.si,segments_e,write.lock) are created in the data directory (E:\elasticsearch-6.1.1\data\nodes\0\indices\atLl0jUNTbuAJKT3OxgpUQ\4\index).
I want to know which among these file contains to exact data that i have indexed.

2.I tired to view these files but they are not human readable.Is there any way to view the actual data

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817542/how-data-is-stored-physically-in-elastic-search/37819282#37819282

Comment: which directory should i give when starting the luke.I keep getting Invalid index error

Comment: Probably that Luke is not able to read an index from ES 6.1.1

Comment: Is there any other way to read the data?

Comment: You may want to try this one, too: https://github.com/javasoze/clue

Comment: hi Val,can i have any link that gives a detailed explanation on which kind of data is stored in respective individual file?

Comment: what do you get when running `curl localhost:9200`, i.e. which version of Lucene do you have?

Comment: sorry val i am using kibana's sense tool,can i know command  to get the lucene version from that

Comment: Just run `GET /`

Comment: "lucene_version": "7.1.0",

Comment: There you go: https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene70/package-summary.html#package.description

Comment: I think @Val is right. I'd use the right version of Luke. I have ES 6.1.1 installed. I couldn't open its indices with Luke v6, so I installed Luke 7.2.0 and it worked.

Comment: how should i run luke 7.2.0

Comment: Thank a lot Val and Krause,it worked with luke 7.2.0 and can i have some link that would explain about the contents showed by luke.I just opened a (.cfe) file and couldn't understand the contents

Comment: hi @Val , I opened a (.cfs ) file and I chose a document number and when i tried to view its _source field using Reconstruct&edit option, the stored field content that is displayed is in some address format and is not readable,how can i view the source string

Comment: In the link I provided earlier, you land on this for cfe files: https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50CompoundFormat.html

Comment: but the stored field contents are not human readable,it is displaying some number values(hexadecimal),but a tutorial at (https://lingpipe-blog.com/2012/07/24/using-luke-the-lucene-index-browser-to-develop-search-queries/) says the fields will be displayed in the form of string when using reconstruct&edit option

Comment: Am I missing something here?