# Elasticsearch database: Where does elasticsearch store data?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, search, nosql

I am curious to know how exactly elasticsearch manages data at its server? Does it have an inbuilt nosql database or does it store in files or is it using some existing db like mysql, mongodb etc?

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819282/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch internally uses Lucene which uses the segments(stored in file system) to store the actual data and it uses the inverted index to enable the fast search capabilities.

Please refer [elasticsearch official blog on bottom up](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up) which explains above statment in quite detail with examples.